# How to solarize LXTerminal and nano

Tags: lxterminal

I just got Raspberry pi and I'm new to linux overall. Enjoying so far, except default color schemes are tiring my eyes. I found nice color scheme [Solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized), but I can't figure it out how to apply it to LXTerminal 0.2.0 and nano 2.2.6.

I'm running Linux raspberrypi 4.9.35.

I would really appreciate some guidance on how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solarized is [apparently built-in to LXTerminal 0.3.0](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/317841/184220). One solution to your problem would be to upgrade to  0.3.0, which is available [in the Stretch repository](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/lxterminal).

It doesn't look like LXTerminal is in Backports, so upgrading to Stretch would probably be necessary here.

---

Alternatively, if you don't want to upgrade your whole system just for that, you could try using [`solarized-termcolor-osc4`](https://github.com/benley/solarized-termcolor-osc4) which is supposed to be a close approximation to Solarized.

If you download that `.sh` file and put it somewhere in your home directory, you'll just need to add a line in your `~/.bashrc` to run the script every time your terminal starts. You'll probably need something like this on a new line in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
~/solarized.sh
```

This assumes you save the file as `solarized.sh` in your home directory. Also, remember to set `+x` in your terminal (you only need to do this once—don't put it in the `.bashrc`):

```
$ chmod +x ~/solarized.sh
```

Comment: I just finished upgrading to Stretch, all went smooth. Indeed in this version you can just pick color scheme, which is very handy. Also thank you for help second time :)